# Free AI music genre recognition for local files

Tags: gratis, music, artificial-intelligence, tags

I'm wondering if there's any music genre detection which meets these criteria:

- it's free
- works on Windows/Linux
- works with files on your disk, doesn't have to be offline, but it shouldn't require upload of whole files anywhere
- adds tags to the files, as a bonus it'd be nice if the tags were modifiable

Does anything like this exist?